# Webapp QR Scanner - iOS limitations?

Tags: ios, web-applications, android-camera, qr-code, ios-camera

not a coder so please bare with me, just in need of expert help!

Currently investigating the possible limitations of using a web based camera QR scanner, like scanapp.org on iOS.

I need a webapp QR scanner that can scan QR's consistently. The issue I am finding is that these web app's works much better on android devices over iOS.

1. Can they be coded to make full use of camera functionality on iOS?
2. Why is it much better via android that iOS?

Web app camera QR scanners not scanning/ barely scanning on iOS but the same site works excellently under android.
What codes underpins this?
Can this be coded out for iOS? or is it software limitation

Comment: I think you will get more answers on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @uspython *Which* Stack Exchange? [There are about 180 of them](https://stackexchange.com/sites), and with such vague guidance, OP chose to repost this on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/398062/461068), where it's blatantly off-topic.